# Timefold : using recommendFit or SolverEventListener to get banch of solutions

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner, timefold

I have a planning problem with timefold. i want to get multiple best solutions. I want an example using recommendFit of SolutionManager or SolverEventListener listen to `bestSolutionChanged()` ( preferably the example of optimizing the school timetable for students and teachers) instead of having a single solution I want to have several best solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There's [a section in the docs on recommendFit() with some sample code](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/responding-to-change/responding-to-change#usingRecommendedFitAPI).

We currently lack at least one [quickstart](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts) that demonstrates it and a blog post about it. Coming soon.